# Specify multiple versions in manifest file

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I've developed an extension(component + plugin) that is compatible with both joomla versions 2.5 and 3.0.

Now, my question is how to declare the version attribute in extension tag in manifest file, since same extension will be used for joomla 2.5 and 3.0 installs. Or does it not matter?

```
<extension version="2.5" ... ></extension>
<extension version="3.0" ... ></extension>
```

Although during install, it doesn't create any problem, as I've tried setting it to 2.5 for joomla 3.0 also

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Seriously you complain about not getting an answer in 31 minutes? You'd better ask for a refund for the money you paid...

Comment: It was not a complaint. And yes, I 'did' mentioned it early I believe, as 31 minutes is quite a less time. Agree with u on that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so not having received even a single response in so much time, I checked the versions mentioned in other commercially successfdully extensions from joomla site those were supporting both the joomla versions, and found out that they were mentioning 2.5.

Hence, im going by the same...